# Why :execute is not working as expected in Vim: LearnVimscriptTheHardWay

Tags: vim

I am trying to learn Vimscript from `LearnVimscriptTHW` and I came across the use of `:execute and :normal`.

[Example from LVSTHW](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/16.html):

```
:normal! gg/a<cr>
```

**From book:**
The problem is that `normal!` doesn't recognize "special characters" like `<cr>`. There are a number of ways around this, but the easiest to use and read is `execute`.

Now when I use `:execute "normal! gg/a<cr>"` it doesn't work for me. It doesn't search for `a(char)` in my current file instead of that it just executes `gg` and than do nothing but if is use `:execute "normal! gg/a\r"` it works and successfully highlights the `char a` in my file.

I also tried the below following ways but none of them worked.

```
:execute "normal! gg/a"<cr>
:execute normal! gg/a<cr>
:execute "normal! gg/a<cr>"<cr>
```

From the book it seems that `execute` internally converts `<cr> to \r`. So, why it is not happening in my case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to escape the `<cr>` with a backslash: `exe "norm! iHello\<cr>World"`

Comment: Ok it worked but I was in the illusion that `execute` will handle everything including the `escaping the sp. chars`. So, is there any Vim function in which I can wrap my above command so that it handles the chars which needs to escaped automatically. Something like `exe "norm! escapefunc(iHello\<cr>World)`

Comment: Well, when using `norm` you'll have to escape the special characters because otherwise vim doesn't know if you want to type `<cr>` or execute `\r`. Outside of `norm` this works automatically.

Comment: Yes, use `escape("iHello\<cr>World")` or get into the habit of using literal notation as in my answer.

Comment: @romainl That doesn't work. It needs two arguments and accepts characters, not special blocks like `<cr>`.

Comment: You could do `escape("iHello<cr>World", "<")` but that will escape all `<` characters.

Comment: @Conner: Yes you are right I need to escape the special characters because `:h execute` also mentions to escape sp. chars.

Answer (score 4):

A look at `:help :execute` may be useful, here. You must escape any `<CR>` or `<ESC>` with a backslash when you use them in an expression: `\<CR>`, `\<Esc>`… These notations are valid only in mappings, if I understand correctly.

Another option is to input the key "literally":

- `i` get into insert mode, unneeded if yoou are on the command line
- `<C-v>`
- `<CR>`

You'll obtain a single character that looks like `^M` and doesn't need to be escaped.